# Split multidimensional array and then slice it

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, split, slice

I have a column of paths:

```
C:\Series1\Season1\Ep1
C:\Series1\Season2\Ep1
C:\Series2\Season1\Ep1
C:\Series2\Season2\Ep1
C:\Series3\Season1\Ep1
```

I now want to split the array into a multidimensional one, so it looks like this in the end:

```
+---+----+---------+---------+-----+
|   | 1  |    2    |    3    |  4  |
+---+----+---------+---------+-----+
| 1 | C: | Series1 | Season1 | Ep1 |
| 2 | C: | Series1 | Season2 | Ep1 |
| 3 | C: | Series2 | Season1 | Ep1 |
| 4 | C: | Series2 | Season2 | Ep1 |
| 5 | C: | Series3 | Season1 | Ep1 |
+---+----+---------+---------+-----+
```

I then have a function called `unique(checkArray)` that checks the number of unique values in an array. I want to have this function check every column 1 by 1.

```
Debug.Print uniqueValues(Column1)
Debug.Print uniqueValues(Column2)
Debug.Print uniqueValues(Column3)
Debug.Print uniqueValues(Column4)
```

How do I get the array into that formation and then checked?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub SplitMe()
    Dim values As Variant
    values = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")

    If Not IsArray(values) Then _
        Exit Sub

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim parts As Variant
    Dim partsMaxLenght As Integer
    Dim splitted As Variant
    ReDim splitted(LBound(values) To UBound(values))

    For r = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        parts = VBA.Split(values(r, 1), "\")
        ' Split always returns zero based array so parts is zero based array
        If UBound(parts) + 1 > partsMaxLenght Then _
            partsMaxLenght = UBound(parts) + 1
        splitted(r) = parts
    Next r

    Dim matrix As Variant
    Dim c As Integer
    ReDim matrix(LBound(splitted) To partsMaxLenght, LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted))

    For r = LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted)
        parts = splitted(r)
        For c = 0 To UBound(parts)
            matrix(c + 1, r) = parts(c)
        Next c
    Next r

    uniqueValues matrix

End Sub

Private Sub uniqueValues(matrix As Variant)
    Dim r, c
    For r = LBound(matrix, 1) To UBound(matrix, 1)
        For c = LBound(matrix, 2) To UBound(matrix, 2)
            Debug.Print matrix(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

Output:
C:
D:
E:
F:
H:
etc.
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I want. It's extremely good. One thing, `uniqueValues splitted(r)` will check the unique values per row, I want them per column, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Spurious see the edited answer if it is better now, HTH

Answer (score 0):

You would reference the array the same way you'd reference fields in a table.  Like tables, arrays are also zero-based (meaning, the first column is referenced as 0 instead of 1).  So, if your array is called MyArray, you would be doing something like:

```
Debug.Print MyArray(0) 
Debug.Print MyArray(1) 
Debug.Print MyArray(2)
Debug.Print MyArray(3)
```

Don't forget that you first have to Dim your array.  If you know how many columns it has, you can explicitly Dim it like so:

```
Dim MyArray(0 to 3) As String
```

If not, you can leave it open-ended like so:

```
Dim MyArray() As String
```

You would have to loop through your array to get data from a specific line number, I don't think you can reference it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split function to split your entries, like this

```
Dim episodes() As Variant
ReDim episodes(numEntries - 1) As Variant

For i = 0 to numEntries - 1
    episodes(i) = Split(paths(i), "/")
Next i

Debug.Print episodes(1)(1) ' = Series1
Debug.Print episodes(1)(2) ' = Season2
```

After that, ensuring duplicates should be as easy as looping over each item in the array.

---

Alternately, if you're just looking to find duplicates for the entire path, just create a collection object and load the item into the collection using the path as the key. If the item has already been loaded the collection will throw an error.

```
On Error Goto Catch

Dim episodes as Collection
Set episodes = New Collection

For i = 0 to numEntries - 1
    episodes.add paths(i), paths(i)
Next i

Exit Sub
Catch:
    'duplicate found
```