# Read out wrongly defined multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have an array that I gathered from a code that splits and then slices an array.

*Refer to this question: [Split multidimensional array and then slice it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427248/split-multidimensional-array-and-then-slice-it)*

I have added this line of code: `splitted = Application.Transpose(splitted)`

Now the array is defined the following way:

[image: Array information]

When I try to run the following code:

```
For r = LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted)
    Debug.Print uniqueValues(splitted(r))
Next r
```

I get this error: `run time error 9 subscript out of range`

For reference with the original code, I receive this output:
[image: original code output]

It works fine with my function and I can only imagine that it has to do with the difference in the definition of the array.

The function requires this input: `Function uniqueValues(uniqueArray As Variant) As Integer`:

```
Function uniqueValues(uniqueArray As Variant) As Integer
Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim i As Long

On Error Resume Next
For Each a In uniqueArray
   arr.Add a, a
Next

uniqueValues = arr.Count

End Function
```

This is the code from the function that `dee` provided:

```
Sub SplitMe()
    Dim source As Variant, tempArr As Variant
    source = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A5")

    If Not IsArray(source) Then _
        Exit Sub

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim splitted As Variant
    ReDim splitted(LBound(source) To UBound(source))

    For r = LBound(source) To UBound(source)
        parts = VBA.Split(source(r, 1), "\")
        splitted(r) = parts
    Next r

    splitted = Application.Transpose(splitted)
    'ReDim tempArr(LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted))
    'tempArr = Application.Index(splitted, 0, 1)

    For r = LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted)
        Debug.Print uniqueValues(splitted(r))
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first screenshot is a 2-D array, whereas the second shows an array of arrays. They do not behave the same way: you cannot extract an array from a 2-D array by (eg) referencing `splitted(1)`  You will either need to modify your `uniqueValues` function so it accepts a 2-D array and a "row" index to examine, or extract the "row" from your 2-D array before passing it to the function.

Comment: So I would probably need to transpose the Array differently than I am doing right now, correct? Because ultimately I am only trying to transpose an array of arrays.

Comment: It would help to add your current code, showing both how the array is created, and the code for `uniqueValues`

Comment: What's the purpose of the Transpose() here ?

Comment: I want to have the output as described in the other question. Where all C: are in one column and hence in one array. That is accomplished with the transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SplitMe()
    Dim source As Variant, tempArr As Variant
    source = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A5")

    If Not IsArray(source) Then _
        Exit Sub

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim splitted As Variant
    ReDim splitted(LBound(source) To UBound(source))

    For r = LBound(source) To UBound(source)
        parts = VBA.Split(source(r, 1), "\")
        splitted(r) = parts
    Next r

    splitted = Application.Transpose(splitted)

    For r = LBound(splitted, 1) To UBound(splitted, 1)
        Debug.Print uniqueValues(splitted, r)
    Next r
End Sub

Function uniqueValues(uniqueArray As Variant, indx As Integer) As Integer

    Dim arr As New Collection, a, s As String
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(uniqueArray, 2) To UBound(uniqueArray, 2)
        a = uniqueArray(indx, i)
        s = s & IIf(s <> "", ", ", "") & a
        arr.Add a, a
    Next
    Debug.Print s, arr.Count
    uniqueValues = arr.Count

End Function
```